# efficient way to pass a sub list to a function

Tags: python, performance, list

I'm trying to parse a long sequence of binary data that contains a sequence of serialized structures. I'm able to get the data in memory as a list of integers (let's call it the main list).

For parsing the different fields contained in the main list I'm creating some functions & classes. My question is what is the most efficient way for passing a sub range of the main list to these functions & classes.

I'm new to Python so forgive me if I say something really wrong.

- If I do something like: `parse_foo(main_list[n:N])` I suppose that a new list will be created. If I'm not wrong this method will be very inefficient. By the way, I'm not going to modify the main list at any moment.
- I think I could use iterators (`iterator.next()`). But the problem is that I cannot access the elements randomly.

Comments & suggestion are always more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the functions so that they take the main list, and start and end indexes.

Comment: yeah, but I don't what functions & classes to see the entire main list . They should just see the stream they are parsing. It also means extra work: calculate the absolute position of everything in the main list, which is error prone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to evaluate efficiency, you should leverage the `dis` and `cProfile` modules.

From [`cProfile` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#cProfile.run)

```
python -m cProfile myscript.py
```

From [`dis` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#module-dis)

```
>>> dis.dis(myfunc)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (alist)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, now I need a proper way to pass a the information to the functions for parsing the different fields :)

Comment: If "proper" is being evaluated on "efficiency" as your question suggests, implement both and note the impact to the bytecode and where the hot spots are in the profiler.